# Should I wrap jQuery document ready in a self executing function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a thought to do something like this:

```
(function(window, undefined){
    $ = window.jQuery;
    $(function(){
        // Do some stuff
    });     
})(this);
```

Would you consider this good practice or bad? Does it have any implications for when jQuery(document).ready() would fire?

Comment: There's really no point.  The library already passes you the reference to the global jQuery object as the first argument of your "ready" function.

Comment: You know that `$` is global in your example? You could just omit the immediate function and you have the same effect.

Comment: Yes, I know the $ is global, I was mostly looking for opinions on wrapping the ready function as à practice. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only reason I'd say would be if you have some javascript to run *before* the DOM is ready, and you don't want to pollute the global namespace.

```
(function(window, undefined){
    var $ = window.jQuery;

    // create some variables and/or functions that shouldn't be global
    //    ...and do some work before the "ready()" fires
    var a = 'some value';
    function b() {
        // do some important stuff
    }
    var c = b();

    // Maybe set up a `.live()` handler, which doesn't rely on DOM ready.
    $('.someSelector').live( function() {
        // Some handler code.
        // This works before DOM is ready.
    });

    $(function(){
        // Your DOM ready code
    });     
})(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not needed.  Using a self executable function creates a scope which makes so the variable you create into that scope do not become global.

```
var a = 'Hi';
alert(window.a); // "Hi"

(function () {
    var a = 'Hi';
})();
alert(window.a); // "undefined"
```

In the case of jQuery, it's not needed. The ready function creates a scope already.